# waiting until server is ready for connections. forked process: 7754 child process started successfully, parent exiting

Tags: mongodb

i tried installing mongodb, after following all the steps as per the website when i ran "mongod" in the terminal/Hyper
i got this error

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1dKJ.png)

later i tired with this code
" mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb --logpath /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log --fork "

got another error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N4TR.png)

i'm new to this ,
i'm learning course from udmey , plz help me to create and run mongo in my mac

[link i used for installing mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x-tarball/)

Comment: The output in the title indicates the mongod process started successfully.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: Have a look at the log files.

Answer (score 0):

You can start mongod processes in a variety of ways.  In most distributions you can use either systemd or sysinit.  These make use of a configuration file, usually located at /etc/mongod.conf.  It looks like you downloaded a tarball and are running it manually without systemd or sysinit.

You can also run mongo in a command line mode, like you show with the following options...

```
mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb --logpath /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log --fork
```

... but you can also keep the configuration in a config file and refer to it instead...

```
mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

An example of a config file having the same command line options you used would look like ...

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log

storage: 
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
  journal: 
    enabled: true

processManagement:
  fork: true
  pidFilePath: /usr/local/var/mongodb/mongod.pid

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: localhost
```

Assuming you saved the configuration file to /etc/mongod.conf you can call mongo this way...

```
mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

A couple of points...

This config file will only accept connections from itself - localhost, because that is what we put in the config file.  If you want it to be wide open replace `localhost` with `0.0.0.0`.  Secondly, it uses a PID file to track the process.  It expects to be able to write the file /usr/local/var/mongodb/mongod.pid with whatever account you execute the program with.  Also, it expects the data directory to exist and be writable by the user that executes the program.  The log file directory is non-standard.  Your original post referred to /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log, but the default logging location for mongo is /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log.